# Brightcove Smart Player API mixed with secureConnections Parameter for preventing security warnings

Tags: javascript, video, https, brightcove

So I have multiple brightcove videos on one page and am using the smart player api to have each video stop when another video starts playing. I used the example on the bright cove website here: http://solutions.brightcove.com/cs/smart-player-api/multiple-players.html and that worked perfectly.

My issue is that once I use brightcove's recommendations for a page that uses HTTPS from triggering security warnings, the smart player API stops working. The recommendations are to add these two params inside the video's .

```
<param name="secureConnections" value="true" />
<param name="secureHTMLConnections" value="true" />
```

So it ends up looking something like this...

```
<object id="player1" class="BrightcoveExperience">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
    <param name="width" value="360" />
    <param name="height" value="200" />
    <param name="playerID" value="1150189326001" />
    <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAAA0vRfoQE~,baHF9-H5aHJPAl3cZ-KjgHH9A7WtanGe" />
    <param name="isVid" value="true" />
    <param name="isUI" value="true" />
    <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
    <param name="@Html.Raw("@")videoPlayer" value="1352995359001" />
    <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="onTemplateLoad" />
    <param name="templateReadyHandler" value="onTemplateReady" />
    <param name="includeAPI" value="true" />
    <param name="autoStart" value="false" />
    <param name="secureConnections" value="true" />
    <param name="secureHTMLConnections" value="true" />
</object>
```

It also has you change the script from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sadmin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>
```

So that works and prevents the browser from triggering security warnings, however the smart player API stops working and I no longer can stop a video by starting a new one. My theory is the new params are causing a conflict because if I remove those params and leave in the https script the smart player api still works.

I apologize that I can't post my exact code due to I work for a company that doesn't allow that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Your settings are correct. The smart player API configured for SSL will only work if the web page it's self is loaded with https.

Comment: Okay thanks. Is there a work around to have the smart player api work in this context?

Comment: I'd suggest putting a conditional if statement around the params checking if the page is loaded over https. The https://sadmin will also need to be conditional - there are other questions mentioning nice ways to change that based on https.